# Lead Record Type for Pardot Prospect

Tags: leads, pardot, sync

What is a best practice way of automating the Lead Record Type selection for a Lead that was created from the sync of a Pardot Prospect? For example, in SF there are 2 Lead Record Types, 
1. Sales
2. Professional Services

Some Prospects in Pardot should follow the Sales Record Type process but other Prospects in Pardot should follow the Professional Services Record Type process.

I feel like I ought to be capturing an indicator/value in Pardot, saving it to the Prospect's Profile and passing it in the sync.

Answer (score 2):

Support answered:
Pardot and Salesforce communicate via API. When Pardot pushes a record to Salesforce it sends information in one request containing the data that Pardot have. In Salesforce, the CRM is following a specific order of execution to create or update a record. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm
The issue is that at the moment we send the Record Type info, Salesforce creates the record with this info but then when it follows the rest of the execution path, to the reassignment, Salesforce overwrites the info to the default record type of the for the connector user.

Temporary Workaround:
To fix this issue, we need to have the two actions done in two separate transactions. Instead of using a completion action to reassigned the record you can leave Pardot to create the record and assigned it to a "Pardot" queue for example, then have a time base workflow that forces the assignment following the rules in place in the CRM.

Found this answer here: https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000PZztQAG

Answer (score 0):

I tried another work around and it seems to have worked. I created a custom dropdown field in Pardot called "Lead Record Type ID" with the values that reflect the IDs of our Salesforce Lead Record Types.

Then I used this field in Automation Rules in Pardot to check if a prospect has been assigned to a particular queue and then update the value of the Lead Record Type ID to the desired one. Hence, on syncing SF created the Lead with with the correct record type.